# SSRS seconds format to two digits while calculating average

Tags: reporting-services

I have an average column in my SSRS report which is calculating average time in ddd:HH:mm:ss format. Below is the SSRS expression for it.
=Avg(Fields!DurationSeconds.Value)\ 86400  & "-" & Avg(Fields!DurationSeconds.Value) \ 3600 mod 24 & ":" & Avg(Fields!DurationSeconds.Value) \ 60 mod 60 & ":" & Avg(Fields!DurationSeconds.Value) mod 60.
The seconds format is coming to 13 digit format and I want the seconds to be displayed in just two digit format.[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON0AZ.png)
Can someone help me in having the ss seconds format in two digits?

Comment: Have you tried rounding the number or converting it to a date and then use a format string? Also see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3ec71f0c-be5a-416a-87eb-27a304fc85e3/how-to-convert-number-to-time-formathhmmss-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: How about using round()?

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. My issue is solved